# How to solve for matrix of the linear transformation?? (Coordinates)

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, coordinate-systems

Apologies for a simple question but my textbook is horrible. I don't seem to understand what this notation means.

$$ \left[
    \begin{array}{c}
T
    \end{array}
\right]_b^a $$

I was looking online for resources to help me understand and found the following question:

Suppose a basis for V = R3 is the set C = {(1, 0, 0), (1, 1, 0), (1, 1, 1)}.
And the coordinate vector of an element (x, y, z) is
$$ \left[
    \begin{array}{c}
x-y\\
y-z\\
z
    \end{array}
\right] $$

How would you get the matrix representation of T. The solution is

$$ \left[
    \begin{array}{c}
3&4&4\\
1&1&2\\
1&1&0
    \end{array}
\right] $$

but I don't seem to understand how to get there so can someone provide a brief explanation of what is going on?

Comment: What is the context in which you saw $[T]^a_b$?

Comment: Its is basically in the chapter of linear transformations and finite-dimensional vector spaces. The exact definition in the textbook is that this is called the linear transformation T with respect to he bases b for V and a for W where b = {v1, ..., vn} and a = {w1,...,wn}

Comment: I also got the question from the following resource. https://math.dartmouth.edu/archive/m24w07/public_html/Lecture12.pdf

Comment: ohh. okay thanks. i will check it out

Comment: You might also read the answers to these questions: [1](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1564507/how-do-i-find-the-matrix-with-respect-to-a-different-basis/1564625), [2](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1285678/some-questions-about-notation-in-t-alpha-beta).  Note that others use different notations for this.  For instance I write $[T]_{a\leftarrow b}$ because though I've seen the notation $[T]^a_b$ before, I feel my notation is more intuitive.